# Get NDB query length - using Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

**What is a good way to get the number of query result when using NDB on google app engine?**

Attempted this:

```
query = NDB_Model.query(NDB_Model.some_property == some_value)
if len(query) > 0:    # <-- this throws and exception
    entity = query[0]
```

I apologize that this is probably a very simple question, but it was not clear to me from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you just want to get the first entity from your query. That's what [`query.get()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_get) is for.

```
query = NDB_Model.query(NDB_Model.some_property == some_value)

entity = query.get()
if entity is not None:
    # Do stuff
```

From the docs:

> Returns the first query result, if any (otherwise None). This is similar to calling q.fetch(1) and returning the first item of the list of results.

In a more general form, there's `query.fetch(n)` where `n` is the maximum number of entities to fetch. It returns a list, so you could easily check `len()` on that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I felt stupid when I found the part about using "fetch()" in the docs shortly after I posted this question. But I'm still glad I asked because would have done "query.fetch(1)[0]" instead of the much better "query.get()"

Comment: @ChrisDutrow: No problem! When you do use `q.fetch(n)`, be sure to check the length, because fetch returns _up to_ `n` entities, but it _can_ return less. The `n` is just a limit.

Comment: @voithos **What is a good way to get the number of query result (just the count only) when using NDB ?**.

Comment: @Nijo: `query.count(limit)`. [It's right in the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count).

Answer (score 3):

To get the result count of a ndb query you can simply use [`count()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count):

```
query = NDB_Model.query(NDB_Model.some_property == some_value)
if query.count() > 0:
    entity = query[0]
```