# Best way to get the count of NDB query - App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

What is the best way to get only the count of NDB query result? (with less read operation)

Which one is more efficient to get NDB query result count ? Normal Query or Projection Query ?:

`EmailSent.query(EmailSent.unsub==True, EmailSent.mail_ref==mail_ref, projection=['to_email']).count()`

`EmailSent.query(EmailSent.unsub==True, EmailSent.mail_ref==mail_ref).count()`

I found same kind of question here: [Get NDB query length - using Python on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220653/get-ndb-query-length-using-python-on-google-app-engine), but it's for getting the first query result.

Answer (score 10):

There is a `count` operation.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count

`count(limit=None, **q_options)`

> Returns the number of query results, up
>   to a limit. This returns the same result as len(q.fetch(limit)) but
>   more efficiently.

Comment: Watch out because 'more efficient' in this case will only be by a constant factor. It will still be time and reads proportional to the query length as appengine walks the index. Will also timeout on very large results, you will need to make it paginated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count`. Negligible differences in efficiency if you are able to paginate.

```
list_of_emails = EmailSent.query(EmailSent.unsub==True)
total_count = list_of_emails.count()

offset = int(args['offset'])
limit = int(args['limit'])

list_of_emails, next_cursor, more = list_of_emails.fetch_page(limit, offset=offset)

prev_offset = max(offset - limit, 0)
prev = True if offset else False
next_ = True if more else False
next_offset = ''
if next_:
    next_offset = offset + limit

objects = map(lambda emails: func(emails), list_of_emails)
        return {'objects': objects, 'total_count': total_count, 'prev': prev, 'next': next_, 'prev_offset': prev_offset,
                'next_offset': next_offset}
```

Comment: For folks reading this later: this way of pagination will not work very well.   The `offset` option doesn't actually start scanning the results further down -- it just does the same query and skips the first `offset` results.   So each 'page' you get will be bigger than the last and your final page will actually scan all entities.   You need to use the pagination API provided with a cursor to actually scan starting from a new place and make it efficient.